# How to assign the value to the element of an array of the object and return the updated object typscript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to return the updated values of Current for 'detailsState'.
I tried as below:

```
  export function GetDetailsPayload(payload: INFO, detailsState: DetailsViewmodel, isSaved: boolean) {
  if (payload && payload.SSN && detailsState && detailsState.INFODetail && detailsState.INFODetail.Active) {

    detailsState.INFODetail.Active = payload;
    if (isSaved) {
      detailsState.INFODetail.Current.map((c, i) => {
        if (c.Id == detailsState.INFODetail.Active.Id) {
          c = payload;
          return c;
        }

      });

    }
  }
  return detailsState;
}
```

**Actual result:** `detailsState.INFODetail.Current` is same instead of payload.

**Expected result:** `detailsState.INFODetail.Current` having the value of payload when condition is met for one of the element in an array.

Thank you!

Comment: You're assigning to `detailsState.INFODetail.Current` yet you expect `detailsState.Current` to change?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs my mistake it is detailsState.INFODetail.Current. It is typo. Updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code:

```js
detailsState.INFODetail.Current.map((c, i) => {
    if (c.Id == detailsState.INFODetail.Active.Id) {
        c = payload;
        return c;
    }
});
```

You map over the items in `.Current`, but you don't actually do anything with the mapped result. You probably meant to do this instead:

```js
detailsState.INFODetail.Current = detailsState.INFODetail.Current.map((c, i) => {
    if (c.Id == detailsState.INFODetail.Active.Id) {
        c = payload;
        return c;
    }
});
```

Mind that that will replace certain elements with `undefined` when you don't `return c` within the mapper. You probably meant to return the original value otherwise:

```js
detailsState.INFODetail.Current = detailsState.INFODetail.Current
    .map((c, i) => (c.Id == detailsState.INFODetail.Active.Id) ? payload : c);
```

Comment: Thank you, it updates now and used ? operator as per the suggestion.